# How to properly dispose graphics context - do I need try and finally? (Java 1.7)

Tags: java, swing, java-7, graphics2d, try-finally

How to properly dispose  graphics context - do I need to use `try` and `finally`? Simple example:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    try {

        g2D.drawLine(0, 0, 10, 0);

    } finally {
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is an example from java.awt.Window class:

```
     /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @since 1.7
     */
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (!isOpaque()) {
            Graphics gg = g.create();
            try {
                if (gg instanceof Graphics2D) {
                    gg.setColor(getBackground());
                    ((Graphics2D)gg).setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC));
                    gg.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                }
            } finally {
                gg.dispose();
            }
        }
        super.paint(g);
    }
```

As I see, constructors used are pretty simple, but `try` and `finally` still exits. So I think it would be a good practice to use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In that simple example, there's no need for `try..finally`; `g2D.drawLine` does not throw exceptions.<sup>1</sup> However, if the body of the `try` might throw an exception, execute a `return` statement, or otherwise abnormally terminate the `paint` method, then I would recommend `try..finally` to ensure that the context is properly disposed.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>It could, I suppose, throw an `OutOfMemoryError` or some other unchecked exception. If it does that, though, disposing of a `Graphics2D` context will be the least of your problems.</sub>